# WooCommerce Price display decimal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, cart

I have a problem that could cause me to lose my job because of another person.
**I use this code to sell products in decimal 0.50 cm**

```
// Add min value to the quantity field (default = 1)

add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal');

function min_decimal($val) {

return 0.5;

}

// Add step value to the quantity field (default = 1)
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
    return 0.1;
}

// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');

// Add unit price fix when showing the unit price on processed orders
add_filter('woocommerce_order_amount_item_total', 'unit_price_fix', 10, 5);
function unit_price_fix($price, $order, $item, $inc_tax = false, $round = true) {
    $qty = (!empty($item['qty']) && $item['qty'] != 0) ? $item['qty'] : 1;
    if($inc_tax) {
        $price = ($item['line_total'] + $item['line_tax']) / $qty;
    } else {
        $price = $item['line_total'] / $qty;
    }
    $price = $round ? round( $price, 2 ) : $price;
    return $price;
}
function echo_qty_front_add_cart() {
 echo '<div class="qty">Mètre(s): </div>'; 
}
```

The problem is that in the cart page and on the invoice the unit price does not vary at all

**How to make the unit price (class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount) change as the total ?**

Comment: Can you specify your problem? Wordpress? Woocommerce? Link to Shop?

Comment: It is a problem with woocommerce linked to the display of the unit price